# On-Change Event For WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, onchange

I really new to WPF and was trying to accomplish something on a data grid. I needed to get one of the cells, Member Id, on it to trigger a search to a database and populate the rest of the columns with the results.

[image]

I tried using SelectedCellsChanged and AddingNewItem but they seem to be triggering at weird times.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="FirstTimeGrid"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    CanUserAddRows="True"
                    CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Model.FirstTimeInvoice}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Model.FirstTimeInvoiceSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    SelectedCellsChanged="FirstTimeGrid_SelectedCellsChanged"
                    AddingNewItem="FirstTimeGrid_AddingNewItem"
                         >
```

Answer (score 1):

You should handle this, i.e. perform the search, when the setter of the corresponding column in your data class is set, e.g.:

```
public class Invoice : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Invoice()
    {
        PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    ...

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(MemberId))
        {
            //TODO: search ...
        }
    }

    private string _memberId;
    public string MemberId
    {
        get { return _memberId; }
        set { _memberId = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "") =>
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```